# How to use fieldinfo parameter in text to column code using blue prism

Tags: arrays, excel, vb.net, blueprism

I am trying to use text to columns code using the blue prism code stage,
I managed to do it  in a good way but my results are in xlGeneralFormat but I want them in text format

```
Dim wb, ws As Object
Dim excel, sheet, range As Object



Try


wb = GetWorkbook(Handle, Workbook)
ws = GetWorksheet(Handle, Workbook, Worksheet)

wb.Activate()
ws.Activate()
excel = ws.Application
sheet = excel.ActiveSheet
range = sheet.Range(Reference)
range.Select()

excel.selection.TextToColumns (DataType:=1,ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True,Other:=True,OtherChar:="_",fieldinfo:= "Array(Array(1, 2), Array(2, 2), Array(3, 2), Array(4, 2), Array(5, 2), Array(6, 2), Array(7, 2), Array(8, 2), Array(9, 2), Array(4, 2), Array(5, 2))")

Success = True

Catch e As Exception
    Success = False
    Message = e.Message
Finally
    wb = Nothing
    ws = Nothing
    excel = Nothing
    sheet = Nothing
    range = Nothing
End Try
```

but it doesn't work !

NB. The code works well without `fieldinfo:= "Array(Array(1, 2), Array(2, 2), Array(3, 2), Array(4, 2), Array(5, 2), Array(6, 2), Array(7, 2), Array(8, 2), Array(9, 2), Array(4, 2), Array(5, 2))"`

but it's in **xlGeneralFormat**

Anybody Can help about this case ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could change the column format just afterwards? Like this one:

```
sheet.Columns("A:B").NumberFormat = "@"
```

where you change the phrase "A:B" with the columns you want to format. Or you could do this with a range:

```
range.NumberFormat = "@"
```

Note: "@" is the code for text format.

Comment: the reason that I want to change format during the text to column conversion is that when it is converted in general mode (as default), the long numbers are aproximated like
`022207175820010645000 became 22207175820010600000`

Comment: Oh, I see. I am not so familiar with the TextToColumns method, but after some reading Iearned that the first parameter in these array tuples like Array(1, 2) should be the position of the first character of the field to read, so you maybe cant use the arrays Array(4, 2), Array(5, 2) twice. An maybe you didnt want to extract only one char fields.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an Integer matrix like this.

```
Dim matrix = New Integer(6, 1) {{1, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, 9}, {4, 1}, {5, 1}, {6, 1}, {7, 1}}
```

And use that as the parameter for FieldInfo

```
FieldInfo:=matrix
```

Full Code like this:

```
Dim wb, ws As Object
Dim excel, sheet, range As Object
Dim matrix = New Integer(6, 1) {{1, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, 9}, {4, 1}, {5, 1}, {6, 1}, {7, 1}}

Try

wb = GetWorkbook(Handle, Workbook)
ws = GetWorksheet(Handle, Workbook, Worksheet)

wb.Activate()
ws.Activate()
excel = ws.Application

excel.Selection.TextToColumns (Destination:=excel.Range(Cell_Reference), DataType:=1, _
        TextQualifier:=-4142, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _      
        :=Delimiter, FieldInfo:=matrix, TrailingMinusNumbers:=True)

Success = True

Catch e As Exception
    Success = False
    Message = e.Message
Finally
```